Sapling tree no vertices after convert to mesh, blender 4.2
I use the Sapling Tree Addon in blender 4.2, created a tree and converted it to a mesh. All worked fine. Then i trid to create another tree with that addon, but after converting it to a mesh i had no vertices to select in edit mode, just straight lines, please see screenshot. 
I tried to generate a tree again in a new .blend file and it worked again, in the following screen i show the tree with vertices as i want 
There are no modifiers on the object. When i copy and paste the tree from the working file, no vertices are shown in the final file in edit mode. .fbx Import does not work either.
I also tried the "make a mesh" option in the armature tab, but same result.
I am a blender beginner, any help is welcome.

